# Get signal from when media has ended Qt.Multimedia and QML

Tags: qt, audio, qml, multimedia

I'm creating a music app using only QML and it's going really well and I'm now working on the track queue. I'm using Qt.Multimedia to play the tracks and there is a property that could be used to play next track when the current has ended, but I don't understand how to get the signal.

Here is the doc I'm using: https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtmultimedia/qml-qtmultimedia5-audio.html

There's a EndOfMedia that I was planning of using, but I don't understand how?

Answer (score 1):

It seems reasonable to connect a Slot to the playbackStateChanged() or stopped() signal that checks the status to see if it is EndOfMedia and then plays the next track.

Comment: Thank you, I did just start to try that. Looks promising.